# DataRepeater control in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there something similar to [DataRepeater](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx) Control for WPF?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of them, it just depends on what you want to do.

In the case above, I'd use an `ItemsControl` with custom rendering for the individual items via binding.

Comment: Just to add an excellent (IMHO) Microsoft example about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716788%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using Listbox; rewrite its ItemTemplate and ItemsPanel.

Comment: The one thing I don't like about this approach is that it's close to impossible to turn off the selected item highlighting. Using an `ItemsControl` avoids this problem.

Comment: this is also possible for the listbox with rewriting its controltemplate, but it's really complexer than using itemscontrol.

Comment: Here is how I fix it:
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Border x:Name="ItemPanel" Background="White" >
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

Comment: So you're stripping back a ListBox to the point that it's an ItemsControl (visually).

Comment: That's true, it's a workaround; I will use ItemsControl directly next time. :)